# How to create a custom drupal cms from starting

Tags: php, drupal-6

Actually i need to know how and where the page content for each drupal page comes. So i tried to integrate my own custom theme to drupal. In the tutorial they are saying like i need to create a custom folder and copy one of the default theme like garland/pushbutton to that folder. I got it correctly, but when i check the files and functions in these template the functions used to create the template are different. For example in pusbutton theme we don't have template.php but in garland we must have a template.php file to show the content. So i am getting confused, is drupal don't have standered way of or functions or files to create a custom templete? Also how the data comes in each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good practice to copy the existing core theme folder and put inside /sites/all/themes.
Each theme in drupal is different from the other. For instance the `template.php` is used

`For all the conditional logic and data processing of the output, there is the template.php file. It is not required, but to keep the .tpl.php files tidy it can be used to hold preprocessors for generating variables before they are merged with the markup inside .tpl.php files.`

The only required file involved in creating a theme is **.info** file.

Learn more about [How theme works](http://drupal.org/node/337173)